# How to Combine Tables that have same columns name

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that has the same columns name.

The first Table is PriceList1

```
 id      name      price
  1.       A         6
  2.       B         4
```

The second is PriceList2

```
 id      name      price
  1.       C         3
  2.       D         1
```

The third is PriceList3

```
 id      name      price
  1.       E         5
  2.       F         6
```

I want to combine these tables into one table

```
 id      name      price
  1.       A         6
  2.       B         4
  1.       C         3
  2.       D         1
  1.       E         5
  2.       F         6
```

I use

```
Select * from PriceList1 p1 left join PriceList2 p2 on p1.id = p2.id join PriceList3 p3 on p3.id = p1.id
```

And I use left outer join, join, right outer join, right join.

I always got something like this.

```
 id      name      price     id      name      price     id      name      price
  1.       A         6        1.       C         3        1.       E         5
                               ........
```

Comment: You're looking for [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Comment: You need `UNION` or `UNION ALL` depending on your handling of duplicate rows.

Comment: Thank you so much.